# What is necessary condition with chromatic number is equal to clique number?

Tags: graph-theory

I know that $\chi(G)\geq \omega(G)$ and there is a $C_5$ with $\chi(C_5)> \omega(C_5)$. What is necessary condition show that $\chi(G)= \omega(G)$?

Comment: The short answer is : "no one really knows".  This question was asked at mathoverflow : http://mathoverflow.net/questions/33192/when-is-the-independence-number-of-a-graph-equals-the-clique-cover-number.  If the experts out there have no clear answer, then no one has.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @Pongpat: Check out the notion of "perfect graph".